# Getting Runtime error in opencv due to houghCircles()

Tags: opencv, runtime-error, hough-transform

as I am new to opencv, I have been trying for detecting a circular region from my camera.
And also, I copied the code exactly as it is in documentation, but still it always gives run time error.
" Assertion failed (radius >= 0 && thickness <= MAX_THICKNESS && 0 <= shift && shift <= XY_SHIFT) in cv::circle, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp, line 1877"
plus
"Unhandled exception at at 0x00007FF913AB3C58 in opencv_trial.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000070F96EEF30."

My code is somewhat like:

```
    int main() {
Mat image;      //matrice for original image
Mat image_hsv;  //matrice for hsv image
Mat image_gray;
Mat red_hue_image;   //matrice for binary image
VideoCapture cap;
int camOpen = cap.open(CV_CAP_ANY);

vector<Vec3f> circles;

while (true) {
cap >> image;          //intake the input of camera
if(!image.empty())    //check if camera is working
{
    imshow("window", image);            //showing of image
    cvtColor(image,image_hsv,CV_RGB2HSV);        // conversion of rgbimage to hsv
    cvtColor(image,image_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(image_hsv,image_hsv,Size(9,9),2,2);
    imshow("hsv",image_hsv);                    //showing of hsv image      
    imshow("gray",image_gray);
    inRange(image_hsv,Scalar(110,100,100),Scalar(130,255,255),red_hue_image);           //binary-ing for red color to be white, all others black    
    imshow("processed image",red_hue_image);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    HoughCircles(image_gray,circles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1.0,image_gray.rows/8,100,100,0,1000);
    for(size_t i=0; i<circles.size();i++)
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
     int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
     // draw the circle center
     circle( image_gray, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
     // draw the circle outline
     circle( image_gray, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );

     Vec3i c = circles[i];
     circle( image, Point(c[0], c[1]), c[2], Scalar(0,0,255), 3, LINE_AA);
    circle( image, Point(c[0], c[1]), 2, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, LINE_AA);
    }
    imshow("circles", image);
}
```

// delay 33ms
    if(waitKey(5)==27){

```
break;
}
}
return 0;
```

}

If i remove the houghcircle line, i dont get any run time error and i can see my camerea opened.
but with that line, the program just crashes.
Please, can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
HoughCircles(image_gray,circles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1.0,image_gray.rows/8,100,100,0,1000);
```

specifically the last 2 parameters... min radius and max radius,

try with a value smaller like:

```
HoughCircles(image_gray,circles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1.0,image_gray.rows/8,100,20,0,0);
```

Comment: I have tried that also, but if i remove circles in the parmeter and add , lets say image_gray again(i know, its wrong logically), it doesn't give any run time error. So I think, error is coming because of circles. But as i said, I am new, so i dont have much idea. Thanks for answering :)